# How to use Ansible to automate one-off tasks?

Tags: shell, path, ansible

I'm using Ansible to automate VM configuration for some of our build environments, e.g. setting up the `PATH` and proxy environment variables, installing global Node.js tools, etc. This works great, and it's easy to automate common setup tasks over multiple hosts. All of the tasks are split up over Ansible `roles` to separate responsibilities and for additional reusability.

Now I've run into the following: With a new package installed, I need to change the `PATH` environment variable - it no longer needs an entry that I previously added as part of the Ansible setup.

So naturally I went ahead and updated the Ansible task that I use to set up the PATH variable for new environments and removed the custom entry (I used the `lineinfile` task to create the PATH entry).

```
lineinfile:
    dest: ~/.profile
    regexp: "^export {{ item.regexp }}"
    line: "export {{ item.line }}"
    create: yes
  with_items:
    - { regexp: 'PATH', line: 'PATH=:~/bin:~/node_modules/.bin:$PATH' }
```

I removed one entry from the above `line` part of the item. As you can see, the `lineinfile` task only checks that the entry `export PATH` is present in the file, and if it isn't, it creates it with `export PATH=:~/bin:~/node_modules/.bin:$PATH`.

Now my question: Since the lineinfile task only verifies that the entry exists, but doesn't check the complete value, I need to make sure that all of the existing environments are updated. How do I go about this?

Is there a way to make the `lineinfile` statement smart enough to verify the content of the line as well, i.e. ensuring that the exact line I want is present (at the same time avoiding duplicate `PATH` entries)? Or is this too complex?

The other thing I thought about (and finally did) is to create a one-off playbook that updates the `PATH` variable in all environments:

```
lineinfile:
    dest: ~/.profile
    backrefs: yes
    regexp: "^export PATH=(.*)/opt/foo/bar/baz/bin[\\:]*(.*)"
    line: "export PATH=\\1\\2"
```

Is this a common scenario - creating playbooks for one-off tasks? The benefit is that the playbook is run on all hosts and avoids manual work. The reusability outside of that is minimal, as I only expect to do this once.

Is this the right way to go about this, or is there a better, smarter way for doing tasks like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which version of Ansible are you using? Since what you are describing looks like a bug, because `lineinfile` module should detect that the line changed and update it. I just copy-pasted you first task (just changed the path to the file) and everything works as it should.

Here is the first run:

```
➜  ~  % ansible-playbook test.yml

PLAY [all] ********************************************************************

TASK: [lineinfile ] ***********************************************************
changed: [localhost] => (item={'regexp': 'PATH', 'line': 'PATH=:~/bin:~/node_modules/.bin:$PATH'})

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Than I removed the `~/bin` from the path and ran the whole thing again:

```
➜  ~  % ansible-playbook test.yml

PLAY [all] ********************************************************************

TASK: [lineinfile ] ***********************************************************
changed: [localhost] => (item={'regexp': 'PATH', 'line': 'PATH=:~/node_modules/.bin:$PATH'})

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

As you can see the module detected that I changed the variable and it updated the file. So all works as it should.

Comment: Thanks! I'm an idiot - don't know what I was doing wrong. You're right, it works as expected. I've reviewed my real code (the above was an example), made a couple of modifications, and it started to work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure I completely understand your question, but would either of these work...

(1) Have a single dedicated line in `.profile` for the path that you add an remove.  So in addition to all of your other `PATH` stuff in `.profile`, you have a line

```
export PATH=~/foo/removable:$PATH  # ANSIBLE MANAGED
```

that you use the `line_in_file` module to add and remove.

(2) Make use of the `/etc/profile.d` directory, and then add (via `copy` or `template) and remove a file`/etc/profile.d/temporary-path.sh`that contains your temporary`export` statement.